# Getting R observations back to NodeJS using "sort"

Tags: r, node.js

I am having a weird issue with the `r-script` (npm module) and the passage of the output to NodeJS.

Using:

```
needs("arules")
data <- read.transactions(input[[1]], sep = ",")

library(arules)

# default settings result in zero rules learned
groceryrules <- apriori(data, parameter = list(support =
                          0.006, confidence = 0.25, minlen = 2))

summary(groceryrules)
inspect(groceryrules[1:5])
```

I get the result fine in nodeJS as:

```
[ { '2': '=>', lhs: '{potted plants}', rhs: '{whole milk}', support: 0.0069, confidence: 0.4, lift: 1.5655, count: 68, _row: '[1]' }, { '2': '=>', lhs: '{pasta}', rhs: '{whole milk}', support: 0.0061, confidence: 0.4054, lift: 1.5866, count: 60, _row: '[2]' } ...]
```

However, changing the last line to:

```
inspect(sort(groceryrules, by = "lift")[1:5])
```

I get no output. If I set the interval to `1:2`, it prints correctly the two top observations (by Lift).
Why can't I view more than 2 items when using `sort`?

My code in NodeJS:

```
var R = require("r-script");
var out = R("tests.R");
out = out.data(__dirname+"\\groceries.csv");
out = out.callSync();
console.log(out)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution.

Using:

```
out <- capture.output(inspect(sort(groceryrules,by="lift")[1:10]))
out
```

It correctly puts into a string the inspect output and then passes it to the NodeJS server as:

```
['     lhs                   rhs                      support confidence     lift count',
  '[1]  {herbs}            => {root vegetables}    0.007015760  0.4312500 3.956477    69',...]
```

A simple split in each string should address the problem now, to make the data manageable.

EDIT:
Managed to find a better solution that gets the JSON in the correct format straight away, by using:

```
data = (sort(rules,by="lift"))
as(data, "data.frame")
```

This way it correctly converts the frame to JSON.